# Prove That For $Av=0$, $\alpha \in F$, $\alpha*v$ Is A Solution

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Lets $v$ be a solution for $Ax=0$ prove that $\alpha*v$ is a solution too.

Because in matrix's algebra $\alpha \in F$ can get out, $\alpha$*Av=A*$\alpha$v

$\alpha$v is a solution too.

is it right?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd write it better
$$
A(\alpha v)=\alpha(Av)=\alpha0=0
$$
but your reasoning is right.